# Disable asp:Textbox editing when an other textbox is filled in real time

Tags: asp.net

I have two TextBoxes, and I want to prevent the user from editing one of it while the other is not empty in real time. How could I do that ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a text changed event on the textbox that needs a input firts. Then in you C# side you can do a check in that event to see:

```
    If(string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtbox.Text))
    {
      txtbox2.Enabled = false
    }
    else
    {
     txtbox2.Enabled = true;
    }
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

The interaction you're describing is on the client, not the server, so you'll need to write some javascript to make that happen.

Add this to the bottom of your aspx page.  Depending on the id schema you're solution is using, you may need to inspect the Id's of the textareas in your browser to get their actual DOM element Id's. (note - haven't tested the code, but you get the idea)

```
<script>
    var elDisabledTxtBx = document.getElementById("Your_Disabled_Textbox_ID");
    var elTxtbxThatAcceptsInput = document.getElementById("ID_of_textbox_user_types_into");

    $(elTxtbxThatAcceptsInput).on("keyup", function(el, $e){
      if ( this.value.trim() === "" ){
        elDisabledTxtBx.disabled = false;   
      }
    });
</script>
```